# Can we open A hidden tab or window and submit the form automatically on that tab/window?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form where I add user in to my Application.

Once the form is submitted I want to open a **hidden TAB/WINDOW**.
On the new opened tab I have another form in which I have some values frmo database which i write to a file, So I want to this form submitted automatically. I want this process as background so user does not know about this.

Currently when user hits the submit button a record is inserted/updated into database and then he gets redirected this way:

```
<script>
var id = <?php echo $data['base_ini_id']; ?>

window.open("./edit_ini_custom/"+id+"/"+<?php echo $data['ext']; ?>);
</script>
```

How do I redirect him in background and submit the form at the URI : **`./edit_ini_custom/`**

Comment: I have a very little knowledge about AJAX @AdamAzad so not sure how to  accomplish it

Comment: @AdamAzad is right, Ajax is the way to go. There are plenty of resources online to learn.

Comment: OKay I will try if i can find anything as per the scenario

Answer (score 1):

The method you want to use is a bit dirty I think. Take a look at Ajax, learn it, try it, it was made for this type of request.

You can use Ajax with vanilla JS like [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).
You can use Jquery too like described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp).